How to Convert HTML to Text Suitable for Vector Embedding Models
I would like to convert html files to plain text in a manner that preserves logical structuring of the html in terms of title <h1>  subtitles <h2> sub sub titles <h3>  and let's not forget link's to other pages as well as <code> blocks.  I have seen some old libraries like html2text but do they really work to present the html in an optimal form? especially an optimal form for vectorization? Some suggestion have been using ** Title ** and *** subtitle *** spacing between paragraphs etc. But I need to know what is the optimal format for vector embedding and also what library supports this conversion?
html2text python library, html-to-text nodejs library etc I have tried but, I was expecting everything to be translated into a form that preserved the meaning and semantic relavance of each html tag.
I would like suggestions for the optinal libray to use for this purpose or at least what is the optimal format for html data to be in for vectorization.

Sounds similar to this answer I gave on how to save a website to text.  It would be easy to repurpose.

It is similar and closely related. I still need more info on what's optimal for understanding the text by vector embedding models.

This is what the output looks like.  It's quite clean considering what it came out of.  Also, pandoc is a bit more flexible than html2text.

Its an improvement but I am looking for full preservation html tags implied structure to the document

Assuming your final usage is something like RAG and so you might need to split your page content at a point, I am currently experimenting with this:

first remove out any irrelevant part from the html dom (like header, footer, navigation, social links)

second use a html to markdown library

third use a markdown specific text splitter (you can find such splitter in LlamaIndex or LangChain)
